# User affinity matching SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have two users a mentor and a mentee.

I want to show the mentee a list of mentors based on matching their skills.

So the registration would be a bunch of checkboxes which say...

*Mentee sees:*

**I need help with**

```
[] Branding
[] Marketing
[] Legal stuff
```

*Mentor sees:*

**My expertise**

```
[] Branding
[] Marketing
[] Legal stuff
```

Is there a SQL-server query to match these guys up based on most commonality?

Hope this all makes sense :\

Cheers

Comment: Do you just want to match on the highest number of common selections?  Is an overqualified mentor preferable, or a waste?  Might there be weights assigned, e.g. language skills are worth more than experience in handling nuclear waste?

Comment: Is the set of skills fixed and known in advance or dynamic?

Comment: @Goran it would be dynamic...

Comment: @user92546 it wouldn't matter if they were overqualified...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about starting with something like this:

```
declare @Users as Table ( UserId Int Identity, UserName VarChar(10), Mentor Bit )
declare @Skills as Table (SkillId Int Identity, Skill VarChar(10) )
declare @UserSkills as Table ( UserId Int, SkillId Int )

insert into @Users ( UserName, Mentor ) values ( 'Einstein', 1 ), ( 'Dilbert', 0 ), ( 'Marie', 1 ), ( 'The Fonz', 1 )
insert into @Skills ( Skill ) values ( 'Arithmetic' ), ( 'Chemistry' ), ( 'Dancing' )
insert into @UserSkills ( UserId, SkillId ) values
  ( 1, 1 ), ( 1, 3 ),
  ( 2, 1 ), ( 2, 3 ),
  ( 3, 1 ), ( 3, 2 ), ( 3, 3 ),
  ( 4, 3 )

-- All users.
select U.*, S.*
  from @Users as U inner join
    @UserSkills as US on US.UserId = U.UserId inner join
    @Skills as S on S.SkillId = US.SkillId
  order by U.Mentor, U.UserName, S.Skill

-- Matches for user 2.
--   Should validate that they are not a mentor.
declare @StudentId as Int = 2
select UM.*, S.*,
  ( select count(42) from @UserSkills as USM inner join
    @UserSkills as USS on USS.SkillId = USM.SkillId and USS.UserId = @StudentId and USM.UserId = UM.UserId ) as 'MatchCount'
  from @Users as UM inner join
    @UserSkills as USM on USM.UserId = UM.UserId and UM.Mentor = 1 inner join
    @Skills as S on S.SkillId = USM.SkillId inner join
    @UserSkills as USS on USS.SkillId = USM.SkillId and USS.UserId = @StudentId
  order by ( select count(42) from @UserSkills as USM inner join
    @UserSkills as USS on USS.SkillId = USM.SkillId and USS.UserId = @StudentId and USM.UserId = UM.UserId ) desc,
    UM.UserName, S.Skill
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution.  Note the is_requesting bit in the @UserSkill table.  A single user can be a mentee in one skill and a mentor in another.  Seems the most reasonable approach.

You could expand on the query to also include the skills for each relationship by joining back to the tables again and using some fun string concatenation.

```
DECLARE @User TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY (1,1),
    name VARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @Skill TABLE
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    name VARCHAR(100)
)

DECLARE @UserSkill TABLE
(
    [user_id] INT,
    skill_id INT,
    is_requesting BIT -- true if mentee asking for help, false if mentor offering help
)

INSERT INTO @User 
SELECT 'Alice' 
UNION SELECT 'Bob' 
UNION SELECT 'Charlie' 
UNION SELECT 'Doug'

SELECT * FROM @User

INSERT INTO @Skill
SELECT 'Branding' 
UNION SELECT 'Marketing' 
UNION SELECT 'Legal'

SELECT * FROM @Skill

INSERT INTO @UserSkill
SELECT 1, 1, 1
UNION SELECT 1, 2, 1
UNION SELECT 2, 2, 1
UNION SELECT 2, 3, 0
UNION SELECT 3, 1, 0
UNION SELECT 3, 2, 0
UNION SELECT 4, 2, 0
UNION SELECT 4, 3, 0

SELECT * 
FROM @User u
JOIN @UserSkill us
    ON u.id = us.[user_id]
JOIN @Skill s
    ON us.skill_id = s.id

DECLARE @skill_string VARCHAR(1000)

SELECT eu.name AS [Mentee]
    , ru.name AS [Mentor]
    , COUNT(*) AS [Commonality]
FROM @User eu -- 'eu' for mente'e' 'u'ser 
JOIN @UserSkill eus
    ON eu.id = eus.[user_id]
    AND eus.is_requesting = 1
JOIN @Skill es
    ON eus.skill_id = es.id
JOIN @UserSkill rus
    ON eus.skill_id = rus.skill_id
    AND rus.is_requesting = 0
JOIN @User ru -- 'r' for mento'r' 'u'ser 
    ON rus.[user_id] = ru.id
GROUP BY eu.name, ru.name
ORDER BY eu.name, ru.name
```